# Function keeps return NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

When the window loads, the console is returning indexIn.
But when I run the bottom function, it returns NaN.

```
const recentItem = document.querySelector('.recent-item');

var indexIn;

window.onload = function() {
  var indexIn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("indexInStore"));
  var indexOut = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("indexOutStore"));
  var indexIn = Number(indexIn);
  console.log(indexIn);
}

var indexIn = indexIn;

recentItem.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(indexIn);
});
```

Comment: It's hard to know what the problem is without knowing what `localStorage.getItem(...)` returns in each case. If you pass random stuff to `Number()` it returns `NaN`. The argument is probably not convertible to a number.

Comment: What exactly is `var indexIn = indexIn;` supposed to do?

Comment: It's returning a number: 0, 1, 2, or 3

Comment: You keep redefining the variable; you need to remove the `var`s inside your function.

Comment: can you `console.log(indexIn);` before using `Number()`

Comment: `var indexIn` creates a local variable in the onload callback. It's not the same as the global `var indexIn` variable that is in scope of the click listener.

Comment: Adding to Chris G. answer also, remove the var indexIn = indexIn;

Comment: yes, it returns 0, 1, 2, or 3 regardless if I use Number() or not

Comment: indexIn creates local variable in onload method.  It's not the global so that you can get the value of indexIn in click event. 

I think you should use the querySelector to get the value of indexIn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
const recentItem = document.querySelector('.recent-item');

var indexIn;

window.onload = function() {
  indexIn = Number(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("indexInStore")));
  var indexOut = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("indexOutStore"));
  console.log(indexIn);
}

recentItem.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(indexIn);
});
```

You have `indexIn`defined globally then your are "redefining" it and setting in inside an "onload" function. Not good coding.

Comment: I'm pulling indexIn from the previous page with window.onload, and the console does return (for arguements sake) 1.

How would I pull indexIn out of that function to use within another function?

Comment: Yes, it does display NaN still

Comment: When you click on recent-item or onload?

Comment: Hm... weird... i tried to recreate your code on jsfiddle. I had to manually trigger the onload function and i am able to see 1 and 1 http://jsfiddle.net/0841L7b3/2/ I suppose that if you are seeing the onload 1 then your onload function is being triggered properly.

Comment: Nvm, your solution works, I forgot to delete "var" from inside windows.onload :) Thanks

Comment: Hahaha no problem man. Good luck. Remember to not declare the same variable multiple times and be aware of on which context you are setting the values.